# Subsetting data and plotting two variables on a line chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, linechart

I want to plot a `geom_line()` with 2 countries which are in the same .csv with the date and the data.

The .csv can be found here: [ourWorldinData csv testing positives](https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-testing#tests-per-confirmed-case)

This is my code :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

dfpositividad<- read.csv("C:/Users/BlackMamba/Desktop/R csv/test-positive.csv", encoding = "ASCII", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
colnames(dfpositividad) <- c("Pais","code", "fecha", "positividad")

#To read decimals
dfpositividad$positividad = as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",
                                  dfpositividad$positividad))

#To read the date
dfpositividad$fecha<-as.Date(dfpositividad$fecha)

ggplot(subset(dfpositividad, code == "ARG"), aes(y=positividad, x=fecha)) +   geom_line(stat="identity", size=1,color="blue")
```

I want to plot two or more countries, e.g., Spain, Argentina, and the USA.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. I find it easier to subset the data before plotting it.

```
dfpositividad_sub <- subset(dfpositividad, code == "ARG" | code == "USA")

positividad_plot <- ggplot(data = dfpositividad_sub, aes(x = fecha, y = positividad, colour = Pais, shape = Pais)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0)) + scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format("%d %B"), date_breaks = "1 month", date_minor_breaks = "1 week") +
  xlab("Fecha") + 
  ylab("Positividad") + 
  labs(colour = "Pais", shape = "Pais") + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 14, base_family = "sans") + 
  theme(legend.position = "right")
print(positividad_plot)
```

Plot:

[image]

Comment: I think that the date is not with the correct format. I can`t fix it. I am trying with : as.Date(x, format, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d")   but not works

Comment: Let me see if I can fix the issue. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: i think its OK, but I prefer its possible to plot like :1 Apr, 1 Jun. I thin that plot like english date, some like 04/01/20 (month/day/year) right?

Comment: Fixed. Check out the edited answer for the code. The date format you want is `date_format("%d %B")`.

Comment: Yes! thats perfect!!! Its possible to plot more bigger only one country?

Comment: Uh, I didn't understand your question. Puedes utilizar español si quieres.

Comment: I have write a lot of countries: dfpositividad_sub <- subset(dfpositividad, code == "GBR" | code == "ESP" | code =="ITA" | code =="PRT" | code =="DEU" | code =="FRA") so i want to make bigger the line for my country, Spain, it´s possible?

Comment: I have tried, but don´t work. I don´t know why. Here i have uploaded the .csv with the new row with Line_size data. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TxT3LPBVuLNsqNQpRitrTarywQCNfJk5d4rw48k5uvw/edit?usp=sharing and I have copied your text :   geom_line(size = Line_size)+

Comment: Run `positividad_plot + geom_line(data = dfpositividad_sub[dfpositividad_sub$code == "ESP",], aes(x = fecha, y = positividad, size = 1))` after making the plot for a custom line for Spain.